# what is standard approach to create a responsive website using javascript,php ajax and perhaps zend framework

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am working on a web system currently and plans to heavily use javascript with ajax to make the user interface more friendlier, not fancy as such.

The javascript will be used for client side form validation, data loading from server and creating proper content with the result, also to for floating windows during add/edit or external references.

Here is a scenerio that could clearify my question. A user wants to update card but instead of jumping to another page to verify the available colors,size and prizes of product, those information are shown in a floating window and changes in the floating window can affect the underlying one.

My question is : 1. What are some of the approaches to encounter this situation? 2. Are there any helpful tips, tricks and links on this subject?

I am comfortable with js,php and zend. I would appreciate any advice,tip and tricks, problem solving approach to handle a situation like this! Thanks in advance. Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow proper MVC if using zend frame work

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html#learning.quickstart.intro.mvc

Basically make sure you're using controllers, models, libraries, and view files properly.

As for the popup you can use any number of dialog or modal window jquery plugins, then with AJAX query your MySQL database to check if color, and size option exists and display any messages accordingly within the window.